# how to pass a class as a function parameter in kotlin

Tags: class, kotlin

I have multiple classes in the folder and I want to pass them to the function one by one. For that I am trying to write a function, which takes Classes as parameters.
This is a test function:

```
fun generate(acctType: KClass, actorID: String){
   val builder = acctType.create("test")
}
```

```
generate(testClass, "000125")
```

but when I try to run it like this, it shows an error:
One type argument expected for interface KClass

as I see I should change KClass with something so I need help with that.

Comment: Kotlin classes are of type `KClass`, not `Class`

Comment: try to pass it as generate(testClass::class.java, "000125")

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko oh... I actually tried that too, but I didn't know it needed to be imported. Solved!

Comment: wait its not resolved, now it says  "One type argument expected for interface KClass<T : Any>" @NikolaiShevchenko

Comment: @Saba please provide more detailed example ([mcve]). For now it dowsn't even compile since neither `Class` nor `KClass` have method `create`

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko tried to somehow make it simpler... the class contents are really irrelevant/unnecessary, it could be anything, even an empty class.

Comment: To solve your problem you just need to replace `acctType: KClass` with `acctType: KClass<*>`. But still, you can't create object instances like this. You can use `createInstance()` function to create instances with no-arg constructor, if this is what you need.

Comment: @broot by replacing that, when calling a function, it gives this error "Type mismatch.
Required:
KClass<*>"

Comment: And how do you invoke it? You should do it like this: `generate(String::class, "foo")`. But I think more important is what you really try to achieve with these classes.

Answer (score 1):

you call function like this

```
generate(testClass::class.java, "000125")
```

And change function with high order like this

```
fun <T> generate(acctType: T,actorID: String)
```

Comment: it didnt change the error, " One type argument expected for interface KClass<T : Any> "

Comment: is ::class.java still necessary? considering it doesnt show any errors without it

Comment: its is required

Answer (score 0):

This is example how to pass class type

```
   fun navigateTo(context: Context, cls: Class<*>) {
        startActivity(Intent(baseContext, cls))
    }

     navigateTo(baseContext, MainActivity::class.java )
```